# rm Command not working inside of shell

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, directory, rm

I am on OS X 10.9 using terminal.

I am new to shell scripting but have managed a (semi) working script.

after creating a file called test.sparsebundle and running some other commands, I wish to delete the file after it is no longer necessary.

I run:

```
echo "...Removing $FILENAME"
rm –Rf "$FILENAME"
```

the file however remains after this command is run and the following error is returned:

```
...Removing test.sparsebundle
rm: –Rf: No such file or directory
rm: test.sparsebundle: is a directory
```

I can't figure out what's wrong. I put the following lines of code after the command so I could try a few things.

```
#TEST SCRIPT INPUT
    TEST_CODE=""
    echo "INPUT TEST CODE \(not deleting sparsebundle\):"
    read -e TEST_CODE
    eval "$TEST_CODE"
#TEST SCRIPT INPUT
```

When I enter the same code as before (rm –Rf "$FILENAME") through the user input it works. I don't understand why it won't work from inside my script (file.sh).

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: I don't know if this is a paste issue but the `-` in the `rm -Rf` commands is not an ascii `-`. It is U+0096. I don't know why the eval vesion would work unless you were entering it differently.

Comment: On my bash script I couldn't use `rm -rf "path/to/folder/*"` I had to use `rm -rf path/to/folder/*`  Yes, I had to remove the quotes. I think it's explained here https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/369557

Answer (score 1):

[Etan Reisner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/258523/etan-reisner) (above) [answered this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26599751/rm-command-not-working-inside-of-shell/26600212#comment41813806_26599751)

The - in the rm -Rf commands was not an ascii character, It is U+0096.